# Runtime generation and compilation of Cython functions

Tags: python, metaprogramming, cython

## A brief version

**Is there an easy way to compile a Cython function in runtime given the code of the function as a string?**

## In details

I have a parametrized subroutine e.g.

```
cdef algo(x, params)
```

- the algorithm performs a relatively small number of operations, but is called very frequently;
- `params` are not known in compile time, but are known at the beginning (e.g. set via config) and **are fixed** for the whole life time of the program;
- `algo` can be **algorithmically** optimized for a specific `params` (optimizations go beyond what a compiler can do), however, the number of possible optimized `algo` is extremely large.

In other words, there is a function that receives `params` and yields a code of a fast implementation of `algo` for these `params`:

```
def meta_algo(params):
  <meta magic>
  return code_of_super_fast_algo
```

The question is how one can compile and import the function defined by the output of `meta_algo`?

### An example

Suppose that you have a fixed small set of strings `ys`.
For a given another string `x` you want to compute length of the maximal common prefix of `x` with each string from `ys` and return it as an array of integers. A reference naive implementation:

```
def max_prefix(x, ys):
  result = []
  for i, y in enumerate(ys):
    j = 0
    while x[j] == y[j]:
      j++

    result[i] = j

  return result
```

For example, if known that the strings of `ys` heavily intersect with each other, one can easily compute a comparison tree, but using any tree data-structure will introduce an undesirable overhead. Instead, one can 'inline' this tree structure in a series of `if`s and generate an efficient code.

For `ys = ['aaa', 'aab', 'baa']` one might get:

```
cdef max_prefix(str x):
  if x[0] == 'a':
    if x[1] != 'a':
      return [1, 1, 0]
    if x[2] == 'a':
      return [3, 2, 0]
    elif x[2] == 'b':
      return [2, 3, 0]
    else:
      return [2, 2, 0]
  elif ...:
    ...
```

Comment: You `Cython.inline` almost does what you want,  but it won't generate `cdef` functions.

Answer (score 3):

After digging a little bit deeper into Cython guts, I have found the following pool request:

https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/555

which provide the exact the functionality I wanted:

```
code = """
cpdef int plus(int a, int b):
  return a + b
"""

module = cython_inline_module(code)
plus = getattr(module, 'plus')

assert plus(1, 2) == 3
```

Comment: that PR is still not merged.. in fact, it was open in 2016 so it's unlikely it will be merged soon. Have you found alternatives that are part of core Cython?